# If we pass HTTP client to another isolate, will it use the same opened socket or just open another one?

Tags: flutter, dart

if i'm using http client to keep connection alive to the same server for multiple requests, and i decide later to pass this client to another isolate, so i need for the requests to be done in that isolate. as we know when we create a new isolate, it takes a copy of all the resources that the main isolate has and not the same resources so my question is:
when i pass my http client to another isolate, will it use the same opened socket or it will open another one and i have to close it inside that isolate after the request is done?